# Optimize the regex for multiline matching, both in steps and time

Tags: regex, performance

Regex - should match newlines as well as should end at the first occurrence of a particular format

In reference to [Regex - should match newlines as well as should end at the first occurence of a particular format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61729595/regex-should-match-newlines-as-well-as-should-end-at-the-first-occurence-of-a)

I am trying to read body of the mail from logs (some of them are more than 500 lines).
Sample data looks like: `BodyOftheMail_Script = [ BEGIN 500 lines END ]`

I've tried following regular expressions:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------+
|                                Regexp                                 |   Steps  | Time  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------+
| BodyOftheMail_Script\s=\s[\sBEGIN\s{0,}((?s)[\s\S]*?)(?=\s{1,}END\s]) | 1015862  | ~474ms |
| BodyOftheMail_Script\s=\s[\sBEGIN\s{0,}((?s)[\w\W]*?)(?=\s{1,}END\s]) | 1015862  | ~480ms |
| BodyOftheMail_Script\s=\s[\sBEGIN\s{0,}((?s).*?)(?=\s{1,}END\s])      | 1015862  | ~577ms |
| BodyOftheMail_Script\s=\s\[\sBEGIN\s{0,}((.|\n)*?)(?=\s{1,}END\s\])   | 1681711  | ~829ms |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------+
```

Is there a faster way (more optimal regexp) to match this?

Comment: Note you could edit the previous question rather than posting a new one. Optimizing a regex also depends on the regex engine, are you using PCRE? .NET? JS?

Comment: Use `BodyOftheMail_Script\s=\s\[\sBEGIN\s*(\S*(?:\s++(?!END)\S*)*)\s+END\s]`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xM9jqL/1).

Comment: The above works. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

## Enhancing the pattern

The most efficient from 5 expressions turned out to be

```
BodyOftheMail_Script\s=\s\[\sBEGIN\s*(\S*(?:\s++(?!END\s])\S*)*)\s+END\s]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xM9jqL/1)

The part I modified is `\S*(?:\s++(?!END\s])\S*)*`:

- `\S*` - 0 or more non-whitespace characters
- `(?:\s++(?!END\s])\S*)*` -  0 or more occurrences of

  - `\s++(?!END\s])` - 1+ whitespace characters (matched **possessively** so that the lookahead check could only be performed once after all the 1+ whitespaces are matched) not followed with `END`, 1 whitespace and `]` char
  - `\S*` - 0 or more non-whitespace characters

**Why not a mere `BodyOftheMail_Script\s=\s\[\sBEGIN\s*(.*?)\s+END\s]`** with `re.DOTALL`? The `\s*(.*?)\s+END\s]` will work as follows: 0+ whitespaces will be matched at once, then `(.*?)` will be skipped the first time, then `\s+END\s]` pattern will be tried. If `\s+END\s]` is not matched, `.*?` will grab one char and again let the subsequent patterns try to match the string. And so on. It might take a lot of backtracking steps to reach the end of a match (if it is there, else, it might end in a timeout sooner than later).

## Performance comparison

Since the number of steps at regex101.com is not a direct proof a certain pattern is more efficient than another, I decided to run performance tests using [Python PyPi regex library](https://pypi.org/project/regex/). See the code below.

The results obtained on a PC with 16GB RAM, Intel Core i5-9400F CPU, consistent results are obtained using PyPi regex versions 2.5.77 and 2.5.82:

```
┌──────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│   Regex  │  Time taken                                                     │
├──────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│   OP 1   │  0.5606743000000001                                             │
│   OP 2   │  0.5524994999999999                                             │
│   OP 3   │  0.5026944                                                      │
│   OP 4   │  0.7502984000000001                                             │
│   WS_1   │  0.25729479999999993                                            │
│   WS_2   │  0.3680949                                                      │ 
└──────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

**Conclusions**:

- The worst OP regex is the one that contains a notorious `(.|\n)*?` pattern, it is one of the most inefficient patterns I have seen in my regex life, it always causes issues across all languages. Please never use it in your patterns
- The first three OP patterns are comparable, but it is clear than the common workarounds for a `.` to match any char, `[\w\W]` and `[\s\S]`, should be avoided if there is a way to make `.` match any char with a modifier, such as `(?s)` or `regex.DOTALL`. The `(?s).` native solution is a tiny bit more efficient.
- My suggestion appears to be twice as fast comapring to the best OP pattern due to the fact it matches strings from left-hand delimiter to the right-hand delimiter in chunks, only stopping to check for the right-hand delimiter after grabbing whitespace chunks of text and the whitespaces that follow them.
- The `.*?` construct is expanding each time a char is not the start of the right-hand delimiter, with longer strings, its efficiency will be decreasing.

The **Python testing code**:

```
import regex, timeit
text = 'BodyOftheMail_Script = [ BEGIN  some text\nhere and\nhere, too       \nEND ]'

regex_pattern_1=regex.compile(r'BodyOftheMail_Script\s=\s\[\sBEGIN\s{0,}((?s)[\s\S]*?)(?=\s{1,}END\s])')
regex_pattern_2=regex.compile(r'BodyOftheMail_Script\s=\s\[\sBEGIN\s{0,}((?s)[\w\W]*?)(?=\s{1,}END\s])')
regex_pattern_3=regex.compile(r'BodyOftheMail_Script\s=\s\[\sBEGIN\s{0,}((?s).*?)(?=\s{1,}END\s])')
regex_pattern_4=regex.compile(r'BodyOftheMail_Script\s=\s\[\sBEGIN\s{0,}((.|\n)*?)(?=\s{1,}END\s\])')
regex_pattern_WS_1=regex.compile(r'BodyOftheMail_Script\s=\s\[\sBEGIN\s*(\S*(?:\s++(?!END\s])\S*)*)\s+END\s]')
regexp_patternWS_2 = regex.compile(r'BodyOftheMail_Script\s=\s\[\sBEGIN\s*(.*?)\s+END\s]', regex.DOTALL)

print(timeit.timeit("p.findall(text)", 'from __main__ import text, regex_pattern_1 as p', number=100000))
# => 0.5606743000000001
print(timeit.timeit("p.findall(text)", 'from __main__ import text, regex_pattern_2 as p', number=100000))
# => 0.5524994999999999
print(timeit.timeit("p.findall(text)", 'from __main__ import text, regex_pattern_3 as p', number=100000))
# => 0.5026944
print(timeit.timeit("p.findall(text)", 'from __main__ import text, regex_pattern_4 as p', number=100000))
# => 0.7502984000000001
print(timeit.timeit("p.findall(text)", 'from __main__ import text, regex_pattern_WS_1 as p', number=100000))
# => 0.25729479999999993
print(timeit.timeit("p.findall(text)", 'from __main__ import text, regexp_patternWS_2 as p', number=100000))
# => 0.3680949
```

Comment: Could you please also post the time measurements and amount of steps so readers can compare your answer with the examples posted by the topicstarter?  As the question refers to performance, without these numbers your answer provides little help to people looking for the quickest way. Also useful would be to add more comments *why* your suggestion is better and not just throwing regexp.

Comment: @TheGodfather I hope it is more helpful now.

Comment: BTW I'm not sure which kind of Python you're using, when I tried to run your code, `regexp` was not found (since it's `re` in Python, isn't it?) and `++` is not a valid regexp...

Comment: @TheGodfather See ***using Python PyPi regex library***

Answer (score -1):

Unless you missed some important details in your question, I don't see any reason to overcomplicate the things. Why not use simple `BodyOftheMail_Script = \[ BEGIN.*?END \]`? So you have your start indicator `BodyOftheMail_Script = [ BEGIN`, you have end indicator `END ]`, and you want to match everything in between in non-greedy way `.*?`. Of course it requires flags like `re.MULTILINE` and `re.DOTALL` (if we're talking about Python):

```py
import re

regexp = re.compile(r'BodyOftheMail_Script = \[ BEGIN.*?END \]', re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

The first rule of regexps - do not overcomplicate ;) Someone will read it after you.

Using the same comparison script as in @Wictor's answer, I got following results:

```
OP 1 0.24152620000000002
OP 2 0.28501820000000005
OP 3 0.20582650000000002
OP 4 0.3379188999999999
WS 0.16937669999999994
Subj 0.10387990000000014
```

Replacing  to `\s` is possible and it does not really change the speed (but if you have only space in the actual file, then just use space, do not overcomplicate)

Also if you want, you can add the group to directly get the content, it adds ~0.02s for me, most probably it will be faster to trim each result afterwards instead of using regexp group.

Comment: Your regex is not the same as OP or my regexps. "Do not overcomplicate" is not applicable to *different* regexps.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew of course it's different, but it *does* solve the stated problem `trying to read body of the mail from logs` within the given format unless OP missed some details.